# Does the Mind Blank spell prevent the target from being frightened?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, conditions, fear

Does the *mind blank* spell prevent the target from being frightened by magical means, such as from the effect of a spell, or by nonmagical means, such as from a monster's Frightful Presence? Do those kind of effects affect the mind of the target?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## No

[*Mind blank*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/mind-blank) does not prevent the frightened condition. It prevents the charmed condition, psychic damage, and various divination effects.

The more ambiguous part of the spell states:

> The spell even foils wish spells and spells or effects of similar power used to **affect the target's mind** or to gain information about the target.

This is speaking on the power of the previous protections: immunity to psychic damage, various divination effects, and immunity to the charmed condition. If the spell were intended to work against effects that affect the mind that are not the enumerated protections, those effects would have also been enumerated. [Spells only do what they say they do](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/107637/what-is-the-source-of-the-spells-do-only-what-they-say-they-do-rules-interpret).

#### Some lower level alternatives:

*Calm emotions*, *dispel evil and good*  (against certain creature types), *hallow* (with the **courage** option), *heroes' feast*, *heroism*, and *protection from evil and good* (against certain creature types)

Comment: I think the bolded part should be "similar power", especially emphasize on "similar". If it was not there, any spell, effect that affect the target's mind (including fear, for example) would also be blocked. Because there is "similar", so it refers to the enumerated spell/effect, not spell/effect in general that affect mnd.

Comment: @Vylix, that section means “even *wish* and other 9th level magical effects don’t violate the enumerated rules”

Answer (score 4):

## Yes

> The spell even foils wish spells and **spells or effects** of similar power **used to affect the target’s mind** [...]

Any spells or effects that are used to affect the target's mind are foiled by mind blank, unless they are more powerful than **wish**.

Spells only do what they say they do, but they do everything they say, and there is no flavour text.

[Jeremy Crawford wrote:](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2019/03/03/does-mind-blank-spell-protect-from-all-the-effects-of-feeblemind-spell/)

> The mind blank spell is meant to protect you entirely from the feeblemind spell.

feeblemind is not one of the enumerated effects under mind blank, but it is a spell that affects the target's mind, and as such mind blank protects you.

The list of effects that it renders you immune from is a list of examples, not a restrictive list.

Note that powers that Frighten you without effecting your mind will continue to function.  The DM may decree that some Frighten effects are not effecting your mind.

Comment: Can you support that it interacts this way beyond JC's tweet? [This question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/146904/why-does-mind-blank-stop-the-feeblemind-spell) covers the feeblemind/mind blank interaction and focuses on feeblemind references attacking the mind. Where does the frightened condition discuss mind?

Comment: Barbarian Path of the Berserker, 6th level “Mindless” Rage you cannot be charmed or frightened. PHB pg. 49

Answer (score -2):

Probably.

The idea of mind blank is that it prevents any thoughts/ emotions from going through your skull. Not exactly sure how someone affected by the spell still moves, but that’s not what you’re asking.
If it blocks all emotions, then frightened would fall under that umbrella, wouldn’t it?

Comment: Hey Jacob, welcome to the site! RPG.SE's format lends itself to RAW discussions, as the question-answer-upvote system is good at isolating one best answer. This answer probably needs a bit more citation to back up this take.