# Why does Mind Blank stop the Feeblemind spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

[Jeremy Crawford wrote](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2019/03/03/does-mind-blank-spell-protect-from-all-the-effects-of-feeblemind-spell/) the following:

> The mind blank spell is meant to protect you entirely from the feeblemind spell.

Yet, according to the description of [Mind Blank](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Mind%20Blank), the spell only protects against these effects:

- Psychic damage
- Effect that would sense emotions or read thoughts
- Divination spells
- Charmed condition

The [Feeblemind](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/feeblemind) spell does the followings:

- Inflicts 4d6 psychic damage
- Sets a creature's Intelligence and Charisma scores to 1
- Prevents spell casting
- Prevents magic items activation
- Stops language understanding & communication

Only the first of these effects is explicitly stopped by Mind Blank.

Why would the other effects be nullified by Mind Blank?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

From the [*Mind Blank*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/mind-blank) spell description:

> The spell even foils *wish* spells and **spells or effects of similar power used to affect the target’s mind** or to gain information about the target.

From the [*Feeblemind*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/feeblemind) spell description:

> **You blast the mind of a creature** that you can see within range, attempting to shatter its intellect and personality.

(emphasis mine)

Remember that [there is no flavour text in 5e spells](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/78012/is-there-flavor-text-in-dd-5e-spells) so *Feeblemind* really does blast a target's mind.

*Feeblemind* is of inferior power to *Wish* (since *Wish* can recreate *Feeblemind* and is one level higher) and *Feeblemind* clearly affects the target's mind, so it seems to me like *Mind Blank* would cancel all of the *Feeblemind* effects altogether.

Comment: Could you elaborate why you think "Feeblemind" qualifies as a "similar power"? And do you think it protects against other spells that do not explicitly satisfy the conditions of Mind Blank?

Comment: @Merudo Wish is Feeblemind plus some more and is a level higher so it seems evident that it is more powerful. As for your second question, see [spells only do what they say they do](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/107647/45757)

Comment: Another question: from your reading of the ability, would Mind Blank protect against Zone of Truth? People have voted No (https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/74670/how-does-mind-blank-affect-the-zone-of-truth-spell)

Comment: @Merudo I agree with the accepted answer to that question, though if you have a different reading you should post another answer there !

Comment: @Merudo I think the answer there depends on how you define Zone of Truth: does it mentally prohibit you from lying (i.e. it affects your mind) or is it physical (i.e. Mind Blank won't do a thing)?

Answer (score 11):

## Because of Mind Blank's additional description.

[Mind Blank](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/mind-blank) offers the definitive, undebateable benefits you list in your question. However, it also grants the following benefit (emphasis mine):

> The spell even foils *wish* spells and spells or **effects of similar power used to affect the target's mind** or to gain information about the target.

[Feeblemind](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/feeblemind) clearly affects your mind, and it's actually even less powerful than a Wish spell. It still boils down to DM adjudication, but I think it's safe to say that Feeble*mind* "affects your *mind*".